# Tkinter: Why does the lambda function allow me to use arguments in the command parameter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, lambda

I would like to understand what is happening below.

I understand that we cannot use `arg` when I call the function in the `command` because that means the function that is being executed at this time.

But I don't understand the `lambda` part.

Comment: Did you forget to include part of your post?

Comment: I assume you mean something like `command=lambda: foo(3)` rather than `command=foo(3)`. The lambda expression creates a function that, when called by Tkinter, will call `foo(3)`. Otherwise, you are setting the return value of `foo(3)` as the the callback command.

Comment: No, maybe I didn't express myself correctly.

I just want to understand what is happening when I use the lambda functions with command  parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trying-to-understand-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353135/trying-to-understand-lambda)

Comment: We can simply say that ```lambda``` stops the function from being executed at the point where it is created so that one can pass any arguments to his or her function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
command = lambda x: x*2
```

It's doing essentially the same thing as this:

```
def some_random_name(x):
    return x*2
command = some_random_name
```

In other words, `lambda` lets you create a new anonymous function (actually a *lambda expression*) without having to create a separate function. In most ways it is just like a function, making it a convenient way to create a reference to a function.

For more information see the official python documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html?highlight=lambda#lambda